# Using LaTeX listings throughout the document

Tags: listings, environments

I've got a LaTeX document with a main file and many sub-files. Because we're writing a documentation we use code snippets everywhere. How can I define a listing and use it throughout the documents?

Defining sample:

```
\lstset{language=[Objective]C, breakindent=40pt, breaklines}
\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt}
\lstset{commentstyle=\textit}
```

Edit:
I changed it to:

```
\lstnewenvironment{ObjC} 
{ \lstset{
   language=[Objective]C, 
 ...
  }
}
```

And want to use it like that:

```
\begin{ObjC}
 id foo = nil;
\end{ObjC}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a complete but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. The code you added looks good to me and should work. What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Please share your ideas, expectations, problems in more detailed sentences.

Comment: I would recommend you to define an own listings style using `\lstdefinestyle{<name>}{<listings settings>}` and then use it using `\lstset{style=<name>}`. This is IMHO cleaner and much better to set the settings globally, especially if you need to add some other listings later which should use a different style.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I prefer to define custom environments, so that instead of saying:

```
 \begin{listing}
 ...
 \end{listings}
```

you can use your own environments. For example for `LaTeX/TeX` code I have defined three environments, with slight variations for each (`teX`, `teXX` and `teXXX`). I also define a macro called `\emphasis` to add words that I need to be emphasized:

```
\newcommand\emphasis[2][red]{\lstset{emph={write,void,writeln,#2},
   emphstyle={\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}}}}%
```

Here is the code:

```
%% Emphasis
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}         % prefer old tt font
\newcommand\emphasis[2][red]{\lstset{emph={write,void,writeln,#2},
   emphstyle={\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}}}}%

\lstnewenvironment{teXXX}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}\lstset{%
      escapeinside={{(*@}{@*)}},
      breaklines=true,
      framesep=5pt,
      basicstyle=\ttfamily,
      showstringspaces=false,
      keywordstyle=\ttfamily\textcolor{blue},
      stringstyle=\color{orange},
     commentstyle=\color{black},
     rulecolor=\color{gray!10},
      breakatwhitespace=true,
     showspaces=false,  % shows spacing symbol
     xleftmargin=0pt,
     xrightmargin=5pt,
     aboveskip=0pt, % compact the code looks ugly in type
     belowskip=0pt,  % user responsible to insert any skips
      backgroundcolor=\color{gray!15}, #1
}}
{}
```

The code is too long to turn into a MWE, but here is an image. Pages with code tend to look empty. To compensate I use tow columns for explanatory text in between. I tend to use very few colours, as I find them distracting. To emphasize, I normally use a bold bold font in the same colour as the other keywords. In the image below, I had it changed to red in order to make it visible in a reduced scan.

[image]